# How to use a vb.net module in asp mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, module

The module containts of a bunch of string properties like:

```
Public Module RolRechten
    Private ReadOnly _DienstenRecht = "Beheer diensten"
    Public ReadOnly Property DienstenRecht() As Object
        Get
            Return _DienstenRecht
        End Get
    End Property
```

how do you acces this module in your view ?

```
If Page.User.IsInRole("Beheer diensten") Then
```

The goal is to prevent typo's all around the application and if someone for some unknown reason wants to change the description of a role we don't have to check every if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could import the namespace and then use it:

```
@Imports AppName

@Code
    If User.IsInRole(RolRechten.DienstenRecht) Then

    End If
End Code
```

Also notice that I am using `User.IsInRole`. `Page.User.IsInRole` is classic web forms and chances are it will crash in Razor.

Comment: Ok works like a charm after recompiling the module classlib , thanks!